# How many graduate students in mathematics are there worldwide?

Tags: soft-question, career

There is already a question about the number of research mathematicians [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5485/how-many-mathematicians-are-there), but I was wondering :

> is it possible to estimate the number of graduate students in mathematics worldwide in 2019 ? (Note that, especially since not all of GS stay in academia, it is quite different from the other question.)

Ideally, what I'm looking for is a graph since 1950, with a break-up by country.

For the US, such a graph can be found on a [fine page by the AMS up to 2015-16 data](http://www.ams.org/profession/data/annual-survey/phds-awarded) (published in march 2018), although crucially it doesn't mention the yearly number of drop-outs.

So the main aim of my question is to find the equivalent for other countries.

Comment: I think I found some data for France : this link https://fr.statista.com/statistiques/618628/nombre-doctorants-par-discipline-france/ says that in 2017 there were 2,406 doctoral students in mathematics & their interactions. I'm especially curious about China and India though.

Answer (score 1):

I estimated the amount of graduate math students and especially the amount of math students in general from a theoretical point of view in an analogeous way like the [Fermi-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem).

- There are about $ 8\times10^9 $ people living right now.
- About $ \frac{1}{5} $ of the people are aged between 18 and 28, let's call them young adults.
- About $ \frac{1}{10} $ of young adults is studying.
- About $ \frac{1}{50} $ of students study math.
- About $ \frac{1}{5} $ of math students is studying at graduate level.

This gives $ 3.2\times10^6 $ people who study math and thus $ 640,000 $ graduate math students.

Comment: this seems accurate for a developed country (for France, with a population of 67 million, your estimate would be some 5000 graduate math students, within a factor of two of the correct answer), but I would think it vastly overestimates undeveloped parts of the world.

Comment: Care to give us some error bars on these estimates, Proxava?